# Facebook Open graph API showing extra information

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I share my website on facebook, I got the information I set in my site as follow.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="ICCOTP, COTP" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<meta property="og:title" content="ICCOTP" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.iccotp.com/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="International Council for Online Training Professionals 
" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Default Store View" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.iccotp.com/media/wysiwyg/iccotp-images/darkened_slider5_v2.png " />
```

But in the end, with my website URL, there is a name `" | BY STEPHEN HEYMAN"` facebook scraping. [image]

This is the response I got when I hit the API call explicitly.

```
{
  "url": "http://www.iccotp.com/",
  "type": "website",
  "title": "ICCOTP",
  "image": [
    {
      "url": "http://www.iccotp.com/media/wysiwyg/iccotp-images/darkened_slider5_v2.png"
    }
  ],
  "description": "International Council for Online Training Professionals",
  "site_name": "Default Store View",
  "updated_time": "2017-02-10T11:25:59+0000",
  "id": "1464214416929124"
}
```

There is no STEPHEN HEYMAN in response. Also I've searched my site source code and database but not found there as well. From where facebook is scraping this?

Comment: If you happen to figure it out, please let me know as well. Getting the same damn bug.

Comment: Sure @RaduAndrei Can you please tell me the name/information that facebook is showing in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i've gotten rid if this error by adding the meta tags

```
<meta name="author" content="author name" />
<meta name="copyright" content="author name" />
```

before the tags with `og:property-name`
Not sure which one overrides the default, but i needed both so, i didn't test.